# url.Parse undefined (type string has no field or method Parse)

Tags: парсер, golang

Почему у меня вылетает ошибка `url.Parse undefined (type string has no field or method Parse)`? **У меня все правильно оформлено, но со структурой идти не хочет**, **если я помещу этот код в новую функцию без структур у меня ошибок не будет**.

***Что делать?*** Такая же ошибка когда у меня код в бесконечном цикле for та же самая ошибка вылетает `url.Parse undefined (type string has no field or method Parse)`

**Код:**

```
func randInt(len int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    return rand.Intn(len)
}

func HTTPConnectionHost(url string, port int) {

    type HTTPListingMean struct {
        ListingStructure64          int64
        ListingStructure32          int32
    }


    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    randoms := []string {
      "https://194.106.219.34:3128",
      "http://91.193.130.172:53281",
      "https://91.225.197.197:65103",
    }

    bestProxyServer := randInt(len(randoms))

    proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(randoms[bestProxyServer])
    httpClient := &http.Client { Transport: &http.Transport { Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl) } }
    response, err := httpClient.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")

    } else {
        fmt.Println("Ok")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас аргумент функции перекрыл модуль.

```
func HTTPConnectionHost(url string, port int) {
                        ^^^
```

Переименуйте в `URL`, а лучше `host`.

Comment: Спасибо! Сразу внимание не обратил